# flume posting data into HDFS but characters issues

Tags: hadoop, flume

Below mentioned is my flume configuration.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

a1.sources.r1.type = http
a1.sources.r1.port = 5140
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.handler = org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler
a1.sources.r1.handler.nickname = random props

a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1

a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://10.0.40.18:9160/flume-test
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
```

there is no error in flume log file but when reading file using hadoop command having issue.

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://10.0.40.18:9160/flume-test/even1393415633931

flume log message is hdfs file created is "hdfs://10.0.40.18:9160/flume-test/even1393415633931"
```

Any help appreciable.

Comment: Whats the log message.. pls clarify.. its not clear frm ur question

Comment: HDFS file writing is successful. Only issue is -cat command using hadoop fs is not able to display characters. Seems to be encoding issue / settings.

Answer (score 1):

First, try replacing HDFS sink with a logger to see if your input is correctly arriving.

After that is confirmed, I would recommend trying to adjust flush settings for the sink.  HDFS sink batches events before flushing to HDFS through `hdfs.batchSize`, which is by default `100`.  This is probably the issue, as you will need to send 100 JSON posts before your output flushes for the first time.

Lastly, you may also want to try tweaking `hdfs.writeFormat` which is by default set to `Writable` and not `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a text file so you should use DataStream like this:

```
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.file.Type = DataStream
```